# slideNavigationController disappeared in iOS7 not iOS8

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, navigationbar

i have used in my application slideViewController cocoa control it's work fine in iOS8 but it's navigation bar become hidden in iOS7

[image: iOS7][image: iOS8]

Comment: can you add some code.how did you add sliderviewcontroller

Comment: add it using storyboard using this control pod 'iOS-Slide-Menu', '~> 1.4.0'
in appdelegate  
        [SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].leftMenu = menu;
in mainscreenview
#pragma mark - SlideNavigationControllerDelegate
- (BOOL)slideNavigationControllerShouldDisplayLeftMenu
{
    if (self.isPopUpOpen==YES) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)slideNavigationControllerShouldDisplayRightMenu
{
    return NO;
}

Comment: where is the that button in ur code.show me the place or code where you are adding button and check for the frame might be because that button is going out of frame.did u check the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and I solved adding an UIBarButtonItem programmatically at self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem, because when I link the button with some method or property of the class, the error occurs.

Greetings!